# Adding UITextView as Subview to Map View Causes Unwanted Recenter.

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mapbox, cgrectmake

In my project, I use a button, that when pressed adds a UITextView (textWindow) to a map view (mapView). The issue is when you add the UITextView after you have navigated away from the user's current location on the map. When you add the UITextView then, the map automatically recenters to the user's location, where as I'd like it to remain where it is and not recenter. Is there something I can add to my code that will prevent it from automatically recentering?

My Code...

```
- (IBAction)textButton:(id)sender {

UITextView *textWindow = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 40)];

textWindow.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textWindow.delegate = self;
textWindow.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[_mapView addSubview:textWindow];
[textWindow becomeFirstResponder];

NSLog(@"Text Button Pressed"); 

}
```

Comment: Is _mapView an MKMapView?  I don't recommend adding subviews to it using addSubview.  Instead, try adding the UITextView (or whatever) to the parent UIView and position it so that it simply appears above (in front of) the map view.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found that I somehow connected the trackButton to my textButton. So when I press textButton is calls both methods for text and track. That explains why it tracked as well when I pressed the textButton. I will close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I accidentally connected the trackButton to my textButton while moving buttons around in the storyboard interface. So when I press textButton is calls both methods for text and track. That explains why it tracked as well when I pressed the textButton.